# MariaDB Multiple Row Insert Order

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Please consider below query -

```
DELIMITER $
BEGIN NOT ATOMIC

IF (Select count(*) from t1 where name = 'test') = 0 THEN
    INSERT into t1(categoryId,name, language)
    values
        (NextVal(categorySequence),'test','en-US'),
        (LastVal(categorySequence),'test','de-DE');
END IF ;
END $
DELIMITER ;
```

I want to insert 2 record with same 'categoryId'. To genereate categoryId I am using mariadb sequence https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/sequence-overview/. NextVal() return next sequence number and LastVal() return last sequence number (same as NextVal() function). Above query is working fine if INSERT statement order is left to right(I found in my test). Example: "`insert into x values('1'), ('2')`". '1' will insert first then '2', But I am not sure mariadb will always follow this order or not. Please help me  about INSERT order or suggest me some different query.

Comment: How does it matter? What is the primary key?

Comment: primary key is  categoryId + language (compound key) - language column missed in insert statement. INSERT into t1(categoryId,name, language)
values(NextVal(categorySequence),'test','en-US'),
(LastVal(categorySequence),'test','de-DE');

Comment: So what is the question about? Are you worrying that `LastVal()` might be executed before `NextVal()`?

Comment: Yes right. I am worry about same which you mentioned above "LastVal() might be executed before NextVal()".

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter. MariaDB ensures each insert uses different sequence value.

Why do you care so much which one is executed first? If you really need to ensure a specific insertion order, then execute two separate insert SQL statements.